# What exception to throw for pop when stack is empty

Tags: java, exception, stack

I am practicing Junit testing and I created a small stack class that uses `ArrayList` as the stack.

My `pop()` method:

```
public void pop() {
    if (count > 0) {
        stack.remove(0);
        count--;
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

I am not sure what to do if the `stack` is empty. I want to throw an exception but I'm not sure which one to throw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can throw an [`EmptyStackException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EmptyStackException.html):

```
throw new EmptyStackException();
```

**Edit:**

In this page from [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html), there is an example of the `pop()` method and the exception mentioned before.

Answer (score 2):

What about doing what the standard Java "Stack#pop" does in this case? See [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#pop()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#pop%28%29)

Comment: yea i thought about this as well. but i wnated to go over stacks as well. So i tried to avoid teh stack class